# Fade out text near box boundary and scaling images to fit auto size parents

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fade out text so rather than a harsh clip for overflow the text fades away at the edge (static; not an animated effect).  I'm using an image on top of the background to cause the fade (I may be way off on this approach; let me know...)

Everything works great, the 1px high image scales in width/height perfectly...  to the outermost `<div>`.  I'd like it only to scale to fit the height of `TOP-DIV-Text` but I can't figure out how.

```
<div style="font-weight:bold; height: 100%; width: 200px; white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden; background-color: #7E7EFF;" id="yomama">
<div>
  <img height="100%" style="position:relative; float:right;" width="50%" src="http://s12.postimage.org/o4bptewwp/fadeout.png" >
  <span style="color=green; font-size: 60px;">
  <u>
    TOP-DIV-Text
  </u>
  </span>
</div>
<div valign="top">
    <span style="color:red; font-size: 30px; white-space: nowrap;">
    <div>
    Middle-Div is a chatty guy
    <br>
    </div>
    <div style="color:blue">
    Bottom div has some more text
    </div>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZEDFV/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are achieving is the expected behavior for a floated image. It will unfortunately overflow its container.

If you want the image to stay within the top div then you will need to position the image absolutely, please take a look at my updated example : http://jsfiddle.net/ZEDFV/2/

I updated the CSS for your image to be as follows:

```
.fader {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
    width:50%;

}
```

And I added the following CSS to the `div` that is wrapping the image:

```
.wrapper {
      position:relative; 
}
```

I added `position:relative` to the wrapping div, because we need to position the image absolutely, but relative to the bounds of the div it is enclosed in.

Comment: For some reason I had convinced myself absolute was relative to the window not the parent element...  I figured this fill was expected due to the float.  Thanks!

Comment: It is absolute to its next relative parent. If that makes sense.